# pkcs11-tool doesn't recognise RSA key

Tags: private-key, pkcs#11

`pkcs11-tool` fails to import the RSA private key, even though it's parsed correctly by openssl. It fails with:

```
error: OpenSSL error during RSA private key parsing
Aborting.
```

The key is already in the DSA format and I'm trying to import it using:

```
pkcs11-tool --module ... -y privkey --slot ... -w some/path.der -l --id ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The RSA private key may be encoded in DER in two ways. Either it has a heading defining what key it is, or it may be just a list of fields (as defined by PKCS#1 RSAPrivateKey sequence). `openssl` command itself handles both forms transparently in most cases, but `d2i_RSAPrivateKey` does not. It expects the `RSAPrivateKey` sequence to be directly available.

The required file can be generated from either DER or PEM format file. It's done using `openssl rsa -in ... -outform DER -out ...`

The wrapped format looks like this in `openssl asn1parse` output:

```
 0:d=0  hl=4 l=2370 cons: SEQUENCE          
 4:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :00
 7:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
 9:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
20:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
22:d=1  hl=4 l=2348 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP].....
```

The unwrapped one looks like this:

```
  0:d=0  hl=4 l=2344 cons: SEQUENCE          
  4:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :00
  7:d=1  hl=4 l= 513 prim: INTEGER           :...
524:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim: INTEGER           :010001
529:d=1  hl=4 l= 513 prim: INTEGER           :...
```

Comment: This answer doesn't mention how to produce the file with an expected `RSAPrivateKey` sequence.

Comment: @ideasman42 the second paragraph provides the command

Comment: @viraptor No, it doesn't. The correct command to produce unwrapped key with a newish openssl is `openssl rsa -in key.der -outform DER -out key.der2 -traditional`. But pkcs11-tool does not accept it either.